Can i miss jummah if i have severe hemorrhoids
Salaam alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.
I have very severe hemorrhoids with symptoms like intense burning, itching, and throbbing. I tried treating them with an ice pack and coconut oil but I still feel the burning and itching. I usually walk to Jummah and the masjid is about 5 km away. I fear that I may have trouble walking all the way with these symptoms and will have trouble returning. Am I sinful if I do not go and pray zhuhr instead?
jazakallah khairan

Illness or severe pain is a valid excuse to not join congregational prayers, including Jumu`ah and Eid. Among the evidence of this is the illness of the Prophet ﷺ (see Bukhari 664) and Ibn Mundhir has stated that he does not know of any disagreement on this.
However if the only problem you face is in walking and you have alternate means of transport available then according to some madhabs (such as the Shafi'is and Hanbalis) it is obligatory on you to go to Jumu`ah by using them. Alternates means of transport can be riding an animal, using a vehicle, using public transport, accepting a ride from a friend etc.

may your prayers and fasting be accepted by the Almighty God. You have not committed any sin in this regard because going to the mosque is recommended, and if you go and your illness worsens, then you have sinned because you have harmed your body and you can pray at home. read
